# EmberJS, How to import files using root path?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember.js-2

I have this a `model` in this path:

```
/my-project/app/models/my-model.js
```

And I want to import it from a `route` in this path:

```
/my-project/app/routes/battles/battle/combats/new.js
```

The import sentence looks like this:

```
import MyModel from '../../../../models/my-model';
```

The path is insane, I have to use the *try and error* system to figure out it. Also if I want to import the same model in another component I can't just copy&paste because this path is only valid from an specific path. For the same reason if I change the path of the component importing my model I have to update the import path.

I would like to have path relative to the root of the project, something like:

```
import MyModel from '/models/my-model';
```

Is this possible?

Comment: import Potato from `app-name/potato-folder/potato-file/`

Comment: @Kitler, it works.. can you create an Answer with this comment so I can accept it?.. ups.. looks like someone has already done it :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ember CLI registers everything in `app/` under the project name, so the import should look like this:

```
import MyModel from 'my-project/models/my-model';
```